# How to load a ogm.properties file in a spring project when I want to connect to Neo4J Database?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

[First of all , If I put the ogm.properties into the resources folder , it worked well .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei1T4.png)

[But if I put the ogm.properties into resources/neo4j folder , it didn't work and show the Exception called org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Driver: null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFKo7.png)

I had figured out that 'spring-data-neo4j' jar default to load the ogm.properties under the classpath , not a customized path like what the picture show .

So , I want to ask that how to make it could worked by using the path:resources/neo4j/ogm.properties instead of using the path:resources/ogm.properties .

Answer (score 1):

You should create the `Configuration` object manually and provide the config file from your class path like this:

```
new Configuration.Builder(new ClasspathConfigurationSource("/neo4j/ogm.properties"))
// more configuration if needed
.build();
```

So a minimal example for your Spring configuration could be:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "com.myapp...");
}

@Bean
public Configuration configuration() {
    return new Configuration
            .Builder(new ClasspathConfigurationSource("/neo4j/ogm.properties"))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: What is the import of Configuration ?

Comment: `org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration(.Builder)` Sorry I missed the conflict to Spring's `Configuration`.

Comment: The same problem? Is your project somewhere available on Github / Bitbucket or could you provide some sources like your maven / gradle config and/or Spring configuration?

Comment: Yes , you can clone my project by "git@github.com:Febregaz/graduationProject.git"

Comment: will look into this in detail later, but I saw that you did not add the leading `/` to the path in https://github.com/Febregaz/graduationProject/blob/master/src/main/java/yuzhaoLiu/project/neo4jConfiguration/neoConfig.java#L32

Comment: Now I add the '/' and then I get the exception:java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please add the changes I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515851/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-neo4j-ogm-session-sessionfactory-metadatalorg and then I will check this again.

Comment: spring-data-neo4j can't update to 5.0.0 . It will lost the Neo4jConfiguration that I need . The project on the Github is up to date . I just want to run the test called Neo4jTest.java and hope it can run successfully .