# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.metaData()Lorg/neo4j/ogm/MetaData;

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Here are my code in PersistenceContext.java

```
package yuzhaoLiu.project.testNeo4j;

import org.neo4j.ogm.config.ClasspathConfigurationSource;
import org.neo4j.ogm.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.neo4j.ogm.config.FileConfigurationSource;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("yuzhaoLiu.project.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("yuzhaoLiu.project")
public class PersistenceContext extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(),"yuzhaoLiu.project.entity");
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }

    //The purpose of this method is that I want to change the path of 
    //neo4j's configuration file called ogm.properties.
    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {
        ConfigurationSource props = new ClasspathConfigurationSource("neo4j/ogm.properties");
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder(props).build();
        return configuration ;
    }

}
```

Then I run the Junit Test it return me an exception like below .

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jMappingContext' defined in yuzhaoLiu.project.testNeo4j.PersistenceContext: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext]: Factory method 'neo4jMappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.metaData()Lorg/neo4j/ogm/MetaData;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext]: Factory method 'neo4jMappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.metaData()Lorg/neo4j/ogm/MetaData;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.metaData()Lorg/neo4j/ogm/MetaData;
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jMappingContext(Neo4jConfiguration.java:66)
    at yuzhaoLiu.project.testNeo4j.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c8d8ebc.CGLIB$neo4jMappingContext$7(<generated>)
    at yuzhaoLiu.project.testNeo4j.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c8d8ebc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f976525a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at yuzhaoLiu.project.testNeo4j.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7c8d8ebc.neo4jMappingContext(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 42 more
```

Here is a picture what my project's structure is below .
[my project's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaHUz.png)
The purpose of this method is that I want to change the path of neo4j's configuration file called ogm.properties.I have read a document what the link is https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/ about 'Using a properties file' . And then there is a mistake that I can not solve it .I would appreciate that if you help me to resolve it .

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the versions of OGM related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

will pull in OGM 2.0.1. Look at the  [compatibility matrix](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#_compatibility) to see how the versions interact with each other.

You also explicitly declared the OGM version to 3.0.0. This will cause that the behaviour which lib is used is somehow unpredictable. (It is predictable but beyond this answer)

So if there is no need to stay on such an old version you should update your spring-data-neo4j dependency to something current like 5.0.3.RELEASE. This will also pull in OGM 3.0.3.